# Why can we say that the limits of $f_n$ exist and $f_n\to f$ a.s. by Arzela-Ascoli's theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am reading the one lecture note [Dynamics for Spherical Models of Spin-Glass and Aging](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-40908-3_5).

On page 123. For any time $T>0$, define a sequence of function $f_n(t)\in C([0,T], \mathbb{R})$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Recall that by Arzela-Ascoli's theorem, the compact set of $C([0,T], \mathbb{R})$ is of the form:
$$
K_{M}:=\{f: [0,T]\to R, \sup _{s\le T} |f(s)|\le M, \sup_{|s-t|\le \delta} |f(s-f(t)|\le \epsilon, \forall \epsilon >0\}.
$$

If we can show that $f_n(t)\in K_M$ (or with high probability $f_n\in K_M$), why can we say that the limits of $f_n$ exist and $f_n\to f$ a.s.?

In other words, if we can show that a sequence of functions $f_n$ is uniformly bounded and equi-continuous, can we show that $f_n$ converges a deterministic limit almost surely? If not, does it hold with addition assumption that for every $x, y\in [0,T]$, there exist $C, \alpha>0$ such that
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\le C|x-y|^\alpha.
$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem claims that the subsequence of $f_n$ converges uniformly but not for any $f_n$ converges to $f$ a.s.

Comment: Be precise and coherent in the statements! Do you work with functions of one variable or two variables $s,t$ ? Defined on $[0,T]$, on $[0,T]^2$ or on the diagonal of $[0,T]^2$? Once this is corrected, you know that $K_M$ is compact and not that « the » compact set if of the form $K_M$. Last, if the functions $f_n$ (not their values $f_n(t,t)$) are in $K_M$, it is not sufficient to derive the convergence of the whole sequence. We only know that some sub-sequence converges uniformly.

Comment: I work with two-variable function $f: [0,T]\times [0,T]\to R$. Yes, I agree that some sub-sequence converges uniformly. But I only want to know if $f_n(t,t)$ pointwise converges to $f(t,t)$ almost surely. I just know the fact that converges uniformly implies converges pointwise.

Comment: Without any additional assumption, you can not ensure that the whole sequence $(f_n)$ converges. For example, let $f_n = f_0$ when $n$ is even, $f_n = f_1$ when $n$ is odd. Once again, correct the statement of your question. If the functions are defined on the whole square $[0,T] \times [0,T]$, you have to consider quantities $f(t_1,t_2)$ with two independent variables $t_1$ and $t_2$ and not only expressions like $f(t,t)$. More over expressions like $\sup_{s \le T} |f(s)|$ are meaningless.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Thanks. I have edited my question. My question is that if we can show that a sequence of functions $f_n$ is uniformly bounded and equi-continuous, can we show that $f_n$ converges a deterministic limit almost surely?

Comment: The answer is no: example $f_n$ constant equal to $(-1)^n

Comment: The answer is no, for example when each $f_n$ is constant equal to $(-1)^n$. Why do you ask for an almost sure convergence ? No random variable where introduced in your description